# Scale whole object in normal orientation

Tags: scale, transform-orientation

As the title says, I want to scale an object perpendicular to the normal of a face.

In edit mode it works fine when I set the transform orientation to normal mode.
But in object mode this isn't an option I believe, local orientation doesn't work eihter, because the rotation of the object.

I can eyeball the scale in edit mode or rotate it in object mode, but it needs to be precise for architecture.

Thanks in advance!

Normal orientation
[image]

Wrong scaling orientation in object mode (local orientation)
[image]

Maybe there is an method to apply the rotation of an object to a normal or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Edit Mode, create  a Custom Orientation from the face. (That's the '+' in the orientation dropdown at the top of the view, in 2.8 .) Check 'Use After Creation'..Then back in Object Mode, use it, with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

However, it's probably better to <kbd>A</kbd> select the whole *mesh* in Edit mode, and scale that, because non-uniform scaling of the *object* (giving the object a transform matrix including a non-uniform scale) often interacts in undesirable ways with modifiers and constraints. Either that, or when you're done scaling in Object mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, bake the scale into the mesh by applying it.

Comment: Even better answer than I had hoped for, thanks!

Comment: @Vince .. but see edit.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the edit/information :)

Answer (score 3):

You have some more options depending on your needs...

Shrink/Fatten with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> (displaces vertices along normals) If you need even thickness modify with <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Or Set the Transform Orientation to Normal and move the face.